# Javascript - Breaking Infinite Loop?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do something like this, and end a seemingly infinite loop once a condition is met?  When I attempt it, it crashes my browser as an infinite loop should.  Is there another way to do this or is it not possible?

```
var nL=true;
while(nL){
    if(/* Condition */){
        nL=true;     
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The challenge here is JavaScript is single threaded, so unless your code inside the loop can affect the condition, it will never get hit. An alternative is to use `setTimeout` to create an "infinite loop" that gives other bits of the system a chance to do things.

Comment: Is there anything in your loop that would cause `/* Condition */` to change?

Answer (score 4):

If `/* Condition */` is *ever* true then the loop will end - as `break` will end the loop, irrespective of what `nL` is set to.

Thus the problem is `/* Condition */` is never true.

---

Now, as Matt Greer pointed out, if the goal really *is* to loop infinitely (or to loop a really long time), this must be done in either small batches (such as with `setTimeout`) or off the current global context (such as with Web Workers) such that browser will not freeze.

Comment: Unless condition is `a = !a`, etc.

Comment: @djechlin The condition is not specified, my only assertion is that it is not true. (Or, alternatively, the code provided is not a representative sample of the real problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var nL=true;
    while(nL){
        if(/* Condition */){
            nL=false; // Set to false to exit loop
            break; // Don't need this, if you set nL to false.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh duh, sorry about the typo on my part.

Comment: If you're setting `nL` to false, there's no longer a reason for `break;` correct?

Comment: True, unless the if test is inside another inner loop. Trying to be bit more general, I guess.